# Django table model

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am relatively new to Django and would like to use it to build the back end of my app. I am using Django.DB models and Django rest-framework. I am trying to make a system where each company in my DB has a table that stores 3 records. Item, Price, and Description but I have no idea what type of field that would be or how one would do that. I was assuming that you would use a one-to-many field but there doesn't seem to something like that.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: No, a many-to-one, so a `ForeignKey`. You make a `ForeignKey` from your `Item` record to the `Company` record.

Comment: I recommend you to work on some tutorials first and look for example code eg. on github. Then the concept should become more clear to you and you can ask specific questions concerning your code.

Comment: You need to post you business logic, scenario of how the relation is going to occur, the fields you want to include inside the model. This was people can help you build the model.

Comment: Thank You Willem Van Onsem this helped me alot.